# Is it legal to launch a kayak from a public beach in Chicago?

Tags: united-states, kayaks, beach, lakes

I live in Chicago and would like to get a foldable kayak. As far as I can tell the only thing I need to do to be able to use it in Lake Michigan is get a watercraft registration.

Once I have that registration, can I launch from one of the public beaches?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like it will depend on the [beach](https://www.chicagoparkdistrict.com/parks-facilities/beaches), some beaches have [restrictions on where you can launch](https://www.chicagoparkdistrict.com/parks-facilities/osterman-beach), some don't and some [do not allow kayaks or paddles sports](https://www.chicagoparkdistrict.com/parks-facilities/helen-doria-beach).

It would probably be easiest to [ask the park department](https://www.chicagoparkdistrict.com/contact-us) which beaches allow kayaks or you could go through the [list](https://www.chicagoparkdistrict.com/parks-facilities/beaches) and see if a particular beach allows it.